# Registration action returns the requested resource is not available

Tags: forms, jsp, struts

I've a form with the following code:

```
<form action="doRegister" class="form-signup" >

    <h2 class="form-signup-heading">Please sign up</h2>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password control" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Surname" required>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Born date" required>
    
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form
```

I've two classes: `UserRegisterForm` and `UserRegistrationAction`

`UserRegisterForm`:

```
package com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.action;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class UserRegisterForm extends ActionForm{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    
    /*ATTRIBUTES of the form fields*/
    
    /*METHODS Get and Set*/
    
    public UserRegisterForm() {
        super();
    }
}
```

`UserRegistrationAction`:

```
package com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.Utente;
import com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.db.dao.UtenteDAO;
import com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.exceptions.RegistrationException;

public class UserRegistrationAction extends Action{

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        
        //boolean action_perform = false;
        String action_target = null;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        UtenteDAO userDao = new UtenteDAO();
        
        Utente user = new Utente();
        //ActionMessages errors_mesg = new ActionMessages();
        UserRegisterForm uf = (UserRegisterForm) form;
        if(form != null){
            user.setEmail(uf.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(uf.getPassword());
            user.setNome(uf.getName());
            user.setCognome(uf.getSurname());
            user.setDataNascita(uf.getBornDate());
            user.setNumeroTessera(rnd.nextInt(999999)+1);
            
            
            try{
                if(userDao.register(user)){
                    action_target = "success";
                }
                
            }catch(Exception e){
                action_target = "failed";
                throw new RegistrationException();
            }
        }

        return mapping.findForward(action_target);
    }
```

in my `struts-config.xml` I've:

```
<form-beans>
        <form-bean name="registerform" type="com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.action.UserRegisterForm"/>
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
        <action path="/index" type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction" parameter="page.index" />
        <action path="/signin" type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction" parameter="page.signin" />
        <action path="/signup" type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction" parameter="page.signup" />
        <action
                path="/doRegister"
                type="com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.action.UserRegistrationAction"
                name="registerform"
                scope="request"
                validate="true"
                input="signup">
                <forward name="input" path="/index.jsp"/>
                <forward name="success" path="/welcome.jsp"/>
                <forward name="failure" path="/index.jsp"/>
            </action>
    </action-mappings>
```

My errors report is:

- **type** Status report
- **message** /JAthenaeum/doRegister
- **description** The requested resource is not available.

Why do I've this problem?

Comment: Incorrect resource location.

Comment: Do you think this type="com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.action.UserRegistrationAction" is wrong?

Comment: Post the code, something is wrong with it.

Comment: I added the missing code.

Comment: The action returns unknown forward named `failed`. Change it to the one configured to the action `failure`.

Comment: I've tried to change `failure` to `failed` that is the same, but it doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the **action** parameter in the form: it must be `doRegister.do` in my case, and in `struts-config.xml` the action path is equal to `/doRegister`. So, see the following code:

```
<form action="doRegister.do" >
[...]
</form>
```

and in the `struts-config.xml`

```
<action
                path="/doRegister" <!-- LOOK HERE -->
                type="com.github.jcpp.jathenaeum.action.UserRegistrationAction"
                name="registerform"
                scope="request"
                validate="true"
                input="/signup.jsp">
               <!-- <forward name="input" path="/index.jsp"/>
                <forward name="success" path="/signin.jsp"/>
                <forward name="failed" path="/signup.jsp"/> -->
            </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

The action returns unknown forward named `"failed"`. Change it to the one configured to the action `"failure"`. The following code should replace

```
try {
  if(!userDao.register(user)) {
     return mapping.findForward("failure");
  }
}catch(Exception e){
   throw new RegistrationException(e);
}

return mapping.findForward("success");
```

The exception should be more informative, to tell you the *cause* of the exception.

Also the form should map to the action right

```
<html:form action="/doRegister" cssClass="form-signup" >
```

Comment: But the problem is when the form pass the request to /doRegister that it doesn't find. I've tried every options that you told me before. I've also tried to remove the actions forward in the struts-config and the code in UserRegistrationAction for that. But the probles is the same...so it's in /doRegister

Comment: Change the `form` tag to struts `html:form`.

Comment: I solved it! See my post above, thanks anyway availability! ;)